# Change default sampling input rate for ALSA

Tags: usb, alsa, input, recording, microphone

I am working on Jasper project on Raspberry pi for voice recognition. The problem is that there is a lot of crackling noise when I record with the default settings. After tinkering with arecord, I realised that if I use the "arecord -r 48000 sample.wav" the recording is far clearer and I know is going to work properly for my voice recognition.

But for the life of me I cannot change this to default (using ALSA config). I've tried all kinds of combinations in config file .asoundrc
All it does is, it goes back to recording at Mono 8000 KHz, no matter which sample rate I throw at it.

The question is:
How do I set the recording sampling rate to 48000 and make it default ?
I am afraid I might have to abandon the project altogether.

Comment: What application are you using to play and/or record your audio/speech?

Answer (score 3):

ALSA has no default sample rate, so it must always be set by the application.

`arecord`'s default sample rate is 8 kHz; this cannot be changed without modifying its source code.